# ¿Por qué azuread_app_role_assignment de terraform asigna los roles en "Otros permisos concedidos" y no está el claim en el token?

Tags: azure, azure-aad, terraform

Tengo un app registration el cuál estoy creando con terraform, pero al asignar app roles a otra aplicación mediante azuread_app_role_assignment estos quedan en una segunda tabla llamada "otros permisos concedidos", pero los requiero en "permisos configurados":

```
resource "azuread_app_role_assignment" "poc-app" {
principal_object_id = data.azuread_service_principal.api.object_id 
resource_object_id  = azuread_service_principal.poc.object_id
app_role_id         = azuread_application.poc.app_role_ids["user_poc"]
}
```

[image: De esta forma]

Además si agrego el permiso manualmente a "Permisos configurados" con la opción que me dispone en los tres puntos a la derecha, se agrega a la tabla de arriba, pero no se reflejan los app roles en el token.